# Software/Script/Aplicação para gerenciar acesso a multiplas contas SSH

Tags: ssh

Trabalho com desenvolvimento de websites e possuo salvo, em um gerenciador de arquivos, centenas de acessos SSH de clientes e eu gostaria de alguma solução que "montasse" ou que permitisse acesso rápido aos arquivos dos servidores remotos, já que preciso pegar os dados de acesso no gerenciador de senhas e fazer tudo manualmente.

Comment: [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org)? Dada a sugestão, não sei se esta pergunta é adequada ao site. Ver discussão relevante em http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57/devemos-aceitar-questoes-de-recomendacao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O **[fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/)** em geral é usado para deployment, mas funciona para o seu caso.

```python
from fabric.api import *

env.hosts = ['user@seuhost.com.br']

def download():
    get('/diretorio/remoto/', '/diretorio/local/')
```

Isso é só um esboço, teria que definir todos os hosts que você quer acessar, os diretórios que você quer baixar...

Answer (score 0):

Por um acaso, eu trabalho num projeto que faz exatamente isso com 18.000 elementos de rede :-)

Não acredito que você vá encontrar um produto que resolva isso para você.

O que eu acredito que seja o caminho para você neste caso é rodar periodicamente scripts que copiem estes logs para você para uma máquina sua local, e daí vc automatize sua análise destes logs você mesmo.

Se as máquinas que você administra forem mais ou menos do mesmo tipo, vai ser um serviço bem fácil. No meu caso, o trabalho é bem complicado porque são centenas de tipos diferentes de máquinas, alguns rodando sistemas operacionais que eu nunca nem tinha ouvido falar ;-)

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, vou desenvolver um script que faça isso, pois pelo jeito não tem nenhuma solução. Conheci o [pydio](http://pyd.io/) porém ele fica com um péssimo desempenho quando é acima de 100 repositórios SSH.

Comment: em especial, fique atento em sua ferramenta para assumir que alguns scripts vão precisar de várias tentativas e, eventualmente, vão falhar, conforme a disponibilidade das máquinas que vc vai acessar. Então é legal vc sempre assumir que vc vai precisar de algum tipo de alerta/log onde isso fique fácil de identificar.